# TeamCity Build Agent fails on successful git init command

Tags: teamcity

This is the output of the build log on the BuildAgent

```
[Updating sources] Failed to perform checkout on agent: '/usr/bin/git init' command failed.
stdout: Initialized empty Git repository in /home/switchbuild/BuildAgent/work/915034859a3ac9d8/.git/
stderr: hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
hint: 
hint:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
hint: 
hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
hint: 
hint:   git branch -m <name>
```

The output says it was able to initialize the empty git repo.

The directory where the agent is building is completely empty.

If I run the same command in the directory I get the following

```
switchbuild@nevcv-build5:~/BuildAgent/work/915034859a3ac9d8$ /usr/bin/git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/switchbuild/BuildAgent/work/915034859a3ac9d8/.git/
```

So it was successful the first time and issuing the command again just reinforces the fact that git init worked.

There is output to stderr when running the command, maybe that's why the agent believes an error has occurred...

**Why does the BuildAgent think the output from git init was unsuccessful?**

**Is there a parameter to allow the BuildAgent to continue after git init?**

Comment: Delete all files in the checkout directory before the build: OFF fixes the issue... But i'd like to clean out the directory before the project builds. Not sure if there is a way to get the teamcity VCS section to continue after the output from git init...